# comma separated string javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry it's a stupid question but I'm try to list a sequence of numbers from 1 to a limit and they should be separated by comma. I have a problem. I don't know how to stop the comma. I should have 1,2,3 but I have ,1,2,3. Can you help me? Here is my code.

```
function getNumberSequence(number) {
var result = ""
if(number <= 0){
    return result
    }
    else{
        if(number == 1){
            result = result + 1
        } else {
        for(i = 1; i <= number; i++){
            result = result + ',' + i;
        }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Well when you start of with "number" being 3, what's the first thing that gets appended to the "result" string?

Comment: not understand your question

Comment: @Pointy long breaths mate, no stress

Comment: Yes I understand your question now. But the problem is that I don't know how to move the comma to have in between the numbers and not at the beginning or at the end

Comment: Maybe you could use this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: @pp94 just check to see if "result" is empty, and only append the comma if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a flag (in the example "first") and check if this is your first iteration - if so, don't add a comma but set it to false ... see here:  http://jsfiddle.net/fdfxc5zq/

```
 var first = true; //have a flag that tells you if this is your first iteration - don't add a comma the first time around
        for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                result += ", ";
            }
            result += i;
        }
```

Comment: Ok I change i = 1 instead of i = 0 so now I have want i wanted. Basically the use of the flag reduce the possibility to have the string divided. Thanks Birgit

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, simply declare result with an initial value of 1 and start the for loop with i=2. Solved. (And in case of number being 1, just return result)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner for you:

```
return Object.keys(Array.apply(null,new Array(number))).map(function(n) {return +n+1;}).join(",");
```

Basically, creates an array of length `number`, "applies" it (basically ends up giving `undefined` values to each index), then uses `Object.keys` to get the indices of the array, increments all the items, then joins the whole thing with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy methods:

1) Just add a comma after each number and return a substring of length-1 to get rid of the last comma

```
if (i === 0) return ""; //to avoid substring() issues on empty strings

var result = "";
for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    result = i + ",";
}

return result.substr(0, result.length-1);
```

2) Using array and join

```
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    result.push(i)
}
return result.join();  //default join separator is the comma
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourCommaSeparatedString.split(',');
```